# ¿Cómo utilizo el event.preventDefault() en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy haciendo un formulario con React y necesito que **NO** se recargué la página al enviarlo. Este es mi código:

```js
  const [stateMessage, setMessage] = useState(false)
  async function handleSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const form = new FormData(this)
    const response = await fetch('https://formspree.io/f/mwkyrwoe', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: form,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
      }
    })
    if (response.ok) {
      setMessage(true)
    }
  }
return (
 <React.Fragment>
  <form
    action='https://formspree.io/f/mwkyrwoe'
    method='POST'
    className='formulario'
    onSubmit={() => handleSubmit}
  ></form>
 </React.Fragment>
)
```

Al hacer click en el botón enviar me redirigé a la página de *Fromspree*, pero no quiero que pase eso.

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo hacer esto?

Desde ya muchas gracias :)

Comment: `<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>` ?

Comment: No la ejecutes en el jsx, solo pon onSubmit={handleSubmit}

Comment: @aloMalbarez no está utilizando React con clases por lo que en este contexto no se utiliza el `this`

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar este problema puedes optar por dos opciones:

1. Utilizar únicamente el callback de la función `handleSubmit` en el propio evento del formulario como se ha indicado en uno de los comentarios a la pregunta tal que:

```js
  const [stateMessage, setMessage] = useState(false)
  async function handleSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const form = new FormData(this)
    const response = await fetch('https://formspree.io/f/mwkyrwoe', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: form,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
      }
    })
    if (response.ok) {
      setMessage(true)
    }
  }
return (
 <React.Fragment>
  <form
    action='https://formspree.io/f/mwkyrwoe'
    method='POST'
    className='formulario'
    onSubmit={ handleSubmit }
  ></form>
 </React.Fragment>
)
```

2. Utilizar la función ejecutada tal y como la tienes ahora mismo en el ejemplo que muestras pero pasándole el evento como parámetro tal que:

```js
  const [stateMessage, setMessage] = useState(false)
  async function handleSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const form = new FormData(this)
    const response = await fetch('https://formspree.io/f/mwkyrwoe', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: form,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
      }
    })
    if (response.ok) {
      setMessage(true)
    }
  }
return (
 <React.Fragment>
  <form
    action='https://formspree.io/f/mwkyrwoe'
    method='POST'
    className='formulario'
    onSubmit={ ev => handleSubmit(ev) }
  ></form>
 </React.Fragment>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

recomendación añadir en el documento principal esto, de esta manera todos los formularios no tendran ese efecto de recarga inecesaria:
document.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{e.preventDefault();})